# UITableViewCell Constraints Not Updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, constraints, ios-autolayout

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with `UITextView`, `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` inside. They have a 10 px space between. In some cases I have only `UITextView`, sometimes only collection view etc.

When no text - I have to move UICollection view up by 10 px. And If I have no text, tableView and collectionView it should be zero height.

```
- (void)configureMiddleWrapperState
{
    self.middleWrapperHasNote = self.noteTextView.text.length > 0;
    self.noteTextViewTopConstraint.constant = self.middleWrapperHasNote ? 7.f : 0.f;
    self.staffWrapperTopConstraint.constant = self.middleWrapperHasStaff ? 7.f : 0.f;
    self.tagsWrapperTopConstraint.constant = self.middleWrapperHasTags ? 7.f : 0.f;
    BOOL middleWrapperHasAtleastOne = self.middleWrapperHasNote || self.middleWrapperHasStaff ||
    self.middleWrapperHasTags;
    self.middleWrapperLastTenPixelSpaceConstraint.constant = middleWrapperHasAtleastOne ? 7.f : 0.f;
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setExcludedPaths];
    [self configureMiddleWrapperState];
}
```

The result isn't like expected:
[image] instead of one line.
When only text is looks like expected. 
 [image: When Only Text]

Constraints become work only if I scroll up and down many times.

Answer (score 1):

try add

```
[self setNeedsLayout];
```

after

```
[self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

Comment: It will loop - setNeedsLayout forces [self layoutSubviews]

Comment: So I think you have to move your logic somewere else. Maybe - (void) awakeFromNib will suit.

Comment: In awakeFromNib I don't know how to serve note text etc. Coz It didn't set in awakeFromNib

Comment: Then create a new method that will configure cell with text and then update constraints - (void) configureWithText:(NSString *) newText;

Comment: I've found the issue. Coz my self.middleWrapperHasTags doesn't set correctly when reuse. By the way thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. Coz my self.middleWrapperHasTags doesn't set correctly when reuse.